# Making the bisection theorem rigorous - Munkres Exercise 4 Section 57

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, algebraic-topology, solution-verification

**CONTEXT**

I am trying to prove the following Theorem:

> "Let $\lbrace{A_1,...,A_{n+1}\rbrace}$ be bounded Lebesgue measurable sets in $\Bbb R ^{n+1}$. Show that there exists an $n$-dimensional hyper-plane that **bisects** (i.e. divides into subsets of equal measure) each set."

Assuming the n-dimensional **Borsuk-Ulam Theorem** (*"if $f:S^{n+1} \to \Bbb R ^{n+1}$ is continuous then $\exists x \in S^{n+1}: f(x)=f(-x)$"*), the key idea behind the proof is to consider the sets imbedded in $\Bbb R ^{n+1} \times \lbrace{1\rbrace} \subseteq \Bbb R ^{n+2}$ and to define a function $g:S^{n+1} \to \Bbb R ^{n+1}$ where $g_i(v)$ is the $(n+1)$-dimensional measure of the subset $A_{i,1}$ of $A_i$ such that $A_{i,1} \times \lbrace{1\rbrace}$ consists of those points of $A_i \times \lbrace{1\rbrace}$ that lie on the same side of the $(n+1)$-dimensional homogeneous hyper-plane, generated by the normal vector $v$, as the normal vector itself (i.e. those points $x$ such that $\langle v|x \rangle \geq 0$). Therefeore $g_i(v)+g_i(-v) = m(A_i)$ and $g$ is **assumed to be continuous** so that, by the Borsuk-Ulam Theorem, there exists $v \in S^{n+1}$ such that $g_i(v) = g_i(-v) = \frac{1}{2} m(A_i)$. Finally, the $n$-dimensional affine hyper-plane obtained by intersecting the $(n+1)$-dimensional homogeneous hyper-plane generated by the normal vector $v$ is the desired one.

**PROBLEM**

I would like to make precise and rigorous the statement

> $g$ is continuous

**MY ATTEMPT**

My best try was to show that if $A$ is a bounded measurable set in $\Bbb R ^{n+1}$ and $\pi$ is the $n$-dimensional hyper-plane generated by the normal vector $w$ and translated by the vector $c$ then the function $f: S^n \times \Bbb R ^{n+1} \to \Bbb R$ given by
$$f(w,c):= m(\lbrace{ x \in A-c: \langle x|w \rangle \geq 0\rbrace})$$
(i.e. the measure of the subset of $A$ on the same side of the hyper-plane as the normal vector $v$ applied to $c$) is continuous. The idea would then be to show that the function that sends the vector $v \in S^{n+1}$ to the corresponding $(w,c)$ is also continuous so that its composition with $f$ is a typical $g_i$.

Now, my initial claim could be proved by restricting the attention to the case $c=0$ (indeed the translation can be made to be followed by the computation of the measure and it is clearly continuous). To this purpose I fixed $\epsilon > 0$, $w \in S^n$ and $u \in S^n$ such that $||w-u||<\delta$ and I am now trying to show that the slice of a ball containing $A$ and consisting of the points such that $\langle w|x \rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle u|x \rangle < 0$ has measure $< \epsilon$ for a suitable $\delta$ but I am having some trouble doing it.

**MY QUESTION**

Is my attempt even close to the easiest way available for solving my problem? Is there any easier way that does not involve such convuluted arguments? Any reference for it?

---

Any answer or comment is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself more clearly!

Comment: Can you prove this for $A$ a rectangle?

Comment: @TedShifrin I would say that I have the same problem because at the end of the day is all a matter of showing that the slice of the n-dimensional ball can be made arbitrarily small by taking close vectors enclosing it.

Comment: Which Munkres textbook is this?

Comment: This is not the only way to use Borsak to show the ham sandwich theorem