# Measure of a slice of $(n+1)$-dimensional ball

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is there an easy way to show that the Lebesgue measure of:
$$\lbrace{ x \in \Bbb R ^{n+1}: ||x|| \leq M, \langle x|v \rangle \geq 0, \langle x|w\rangle <0\rbrace}, \hspace{2mm} v,w \in S^{n}$$
is arbitrarily small for $v,w$ sufficiently close?

For anyone wondering, I need this result to answer to my other question which you can find here: [Making the bisection theorem rigorous - Munkres Exercise 4 Section 57](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4762671/making-the-bisection-theorem-rigorous-munkres-exercise-4-section-57)

Comment: Maybe [this 17 June 2005 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/F1_GTvZBEE8/m/DPmjLU3ZxvAJ)?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro From what I could understand, in that post they are discussing about the monotonicity of the volume of the n-dimensional unit ball. I think that my result does not depend on the exact value of that volume but rather on the fact that it is finite and on the fact that any ball is the union of many equal slices (an increasing number for closer and closer boundaries).

Comment: I don’t know why, but `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` seem to do something weird to the format on my reader. The last $v$ appears to migrate inside the brackets, preceded by two commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By rotational invariance, we can assume that $v = (1, 0, ..., 0)$ and $w = (\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}, \epsilon, 0, 0, ..., 0)$ for $\epsilon\to0$. Note then that for $x$ such that $\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}\cdot x_1 + \epsilon \cdot x_2 = \langle x,w\rangle < 0$, we have that $\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}\cdot x_1 - \epsilon < 0$, or $x_1 < \epsilon/\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}$. We also have that $x_1 = \langle x,v\rangle \geq 0$. Then, the measure of the intersections of the caps of $v$ and $w$ is at most the measure of the $(n-1)$-dimensional ball (which is just a fixed constant depending only on $n$) times $\epsilon/\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}$, which goes to $0$ as $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: I think you meant the $(n-1)$-dimensional **disk** (with the solid interior...) but great simplification (+1).

Comment: Indeed, this is the ball in one lower dimension, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: This might just be it! Since I haven’t already seen anything about the measure of a product space, could I just say that the measure of the slice I am considering is at most the measure of a k-cell whose first factor is $[0, \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{M^2-\epsilon ^2}}]$ and the others are $[-M, +M]$ so that this measure also converges to 0 as $\epsilon \to 0$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right!

Comment: @MatteoMenghini a k-cell?! No need for CW terminology here, that has little to do with measure. However the product measure is, at its heart, a simple idea; on the ‘cylinder sets’ $A\times B$ we set the measure to be $\mu(A)\mu(B)$ and then use extension theorems to, in good conditions, have a measure on the whole product space. So here your measure is bounded by the epsilon term * the measure of the (n-1) ball

Comment: @FShrike Sorry for the terminology! However I am following Rudin’s RCA so I would like to stick to where I have arrived so far, meaning that I would avoid product spaces if my argument works as well!